# Cassandra - Heavy reads and moderate updates with large data in one column - Performance issue

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have initial data which when loaded in Cassandra, the total size shown is 3.5GB

After that I do heavy read like 10k reads per second and moderate update like 1k updates per second but in update one of the column size is updated to larger size such that the total size of the row increases from 1k to almost 5k

The storage thing is that size of the Node keeps increasing non stop to even going up to 300GB and only heading up

Compaction is running, read performances keeps on degrading nonstop. Is Cassandra having trouble with updates of row to 5k from 2k ?

This is a AWS 30GB RAM machine with 16 processors and 1TB SSD with 32k IOPS activated. Compaction throughput set at 256 and compactors at 8, still the deviation of reads continue and size of SS Tables increasing

Reads per second degrades from 22k per second to as bad as 5k per second over a period of 1 day

Please let me know what is wrong in the configuration

Comment: On the update are you updating the same row repeatedly? Are you updating the entire row or just a column? Can you provide your schema and queries here?

Comment: There are 30 million rows first pre populated and then sequentially updating them one by one from initial size of 2k to 5k. All values randomised and especially that one column which is most sized compared to all columns in the row

Comment: can you include your existing schema (including compaction settings) and tablestats output?

Comment: Which compaction strategy are you using? Can you post the output of "nodetool compactionstats" and also ssh to the node and check how many SSTable files are present in the data directory? Also, which version of Cassandra are you using?

Comment: Levelled Compaction

pending tasks: 582
- t.cc: 299
- t.ss: 283

Comment: When I do cfhistograms I see most of 50% hitting SSTables of 1 and even 95% percentile hitting SSTables of 2

Comment: @bechbd am updating entire row. Schema is simple. It has 10 fields mostly string and if characters added payload is 5k bytes. And it has a cluster and partition key

Comment: Dear, the problem starts with compaction. The moment compaction comes in action in LevelCompaction Strategy, both Reads and Writes deteriorate.

If I disable compaction, both reads and writes are extremely stable

Answer (score 0):

Basically observe pending compactions and if they increase first start increasing the compaction throughput using nodetool.

If you see that the pending compactions has started reducing then increase it a bit more from that configuration as a buffer.

Also you can increase the concurrent compactors also by small amount if you usee CPU is not overloaded during operations + compaction